# Can't display captured image in pop up using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image saved as a div on a html page. When someone clicks this image I want a pop up box to open and the image that was clicked to be also displayed within the pop up box.

You can see the page here http://kudosoo.com/JQUERYYTEST/dannyboy.html#

Looking at console log I can see that the below code is capturing the image under #go, but its not displaying in the html.

(Please note in the js code below there is also an effect that plays when the user hoovers over the image, this works fine so ignore that part)

What I'm I missing?

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $('#go').click(function(e) { 
            var imgPaht =('#go');

            $('<img src="'+ imgPaht +'">').load(function() {
                $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#go');
            })

            $('#modal').reveal({ 
                animation: 'fade',               
                animationspeed: 600,              
                closeonbackgroundclick: true,  
                dismissmodalclass: 'close'  


            });
            return false;
           });
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: *I have an image: <div id="go"></div>* Is not helpful. What's #go, where's your image? where are you targeting the image `src` attribute? Have you Googled how to get an image src attribute?  `var imgPaht =('#go');` what should be that? var path to an image is equal to .... a DIV element? BTW in jQuery elements are referenced as `$('#go')` using `$`

Comment: Where are the css and all the html?

Comment: What is #modal? Is it before #go?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry for the bad explenation, I know that we are'nt meant to post external links, but this seems the best way to explain what i'm trying to achieve. It also answers questions from other raised here http://kudosoo.com/JQUERYYTEST/dannyboy.html#

Comment: Can you explain better your problem? I'm still trying to understand...

Comment: I've tried to make what I'm trying to achieve clearer by updating the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution was a lot more simple than what I was trying to do originally.

To make the image display in the pop up, all I needed to do was add this to the pop up box

```
<div id= "go"></div>
```

and add

```
$(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#content');
```

to the original code block under

```
$('#go').click(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code to make a **clean** and **light** popup.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.popup').delay(100).fadeIn('medium');
    $('.popup,.outpopup').click(function () {
        $('.popup').stop().fadeOut('medium');
    });
});
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/don/Rf6YW/